# how to click a button this no class, id or value using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click the MLB button on this website, it is dynamic so I don't think xpath will work and no css selector code i have tired has worked. What is the best way to do this?

```
driver.get("https://www.mybookie.ag/")
loginButton = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME,value = "login-btn-box__login")
loginButton.click()

time.sleep(1)

##inputs usernme
driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value = "username").send_keys(mybookieEmail)


##inputs password
driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value = "password").send_keys(myBookiePassword)
time.sleep(5)
##clicks login button
driver.find_element(by=By.ID,value = "login_trk").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="MLB"]').click()

##driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[data-name="MLB"]')
##driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value = 'button[data-name="MLB"]').click()




driver.quit()
```

[mybookie link](https://engine.mybookie.ag/sports/home?first_page=1)

Comment: You should show the html in your question.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-zone="mobile-slider" class="featured-nav-list__item__link request_league menu_item" data-league_id="5" data-breadcrumb="7_200" data-redirect="true">
                            MLB
                        </a>

Comment: Maybe with this css: `a[data-league_id="5"]`